# What do electric field lines tell us?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

Does it indicate the direction of motion of the photons in electrostatic fields (I mean is the direction of the electric line of force the same as the direction of motion of the photons at that point) ? Or is it simply indicating the change of direction of the electric field strength vector?

Comment: Why are you mentioning photons here? Do you mean electrons or other charges? Photons are charge-free and thus wouldn't be affected by electric fields.

Comment: The electric field consists of photons, so I think the electric field line must tell something about the motion of the photons.

Comment: Photons define electric(magnetic) fields at the core of it, yes, but they are not *influenced* by electric fields. Electric field forces only influence electric charges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the extent that a photon in an electromagnetic wave: the solutions to Maxwell's Eq are independent, and can be added. That is: photons don't care about external field lines, they have no effect on propagation.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it indicate the direction of motion of the photons in
> electrostatic fields (I mean is the direction of the electric line of
> force the same as the direction of motion of the photons at that
> point) ?

By convention the direction of the electric field lines (as indicated by arrows) in an area is the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field at that area. The relative strength of that force compared to other areas of the same diagram is based on the relative densities of the field lines.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but does the direction of the electric field lines tell us anything about the direction of the photon's motion?

Comment: @newbieatphysics I don’t believe so . The field lines give information for forces on charge. Photons have no charge. According to the following site they don’t interact with electrostatic fields : https://van.physics.illinois.edu/ask/listing/2348

Answer (score 1):

An electric field line is a line whose direction at every point along it is the direction of the electric field, $\mathbf E$, at that point.

This means that a positive charged particle (such as a p**r**oton) at a point P in an electric field will experience a force in the direction of the field line through P. But if the field line is curved, a moving particle won't follow the field line, because the electric force on the particle at P acts along the field line through P and can't provide the centripetal force needed for the particle to follow the curve.

So field lines are not, in general, the *paths* of charged particles. Instead they are as stated in my first paragraph. Is the  *direction* of the field the only thing they reveal? No: you can get an indication of the how the *magnitude* of the field changes from one place to another, if you have a map showing several field lines. Where they come closer together the field is stronger. A simple example of this is the radial field lines due a positive 'source' charge.

Comment: my question is about motion of photons, not of charged particles. Of course I know charged particles may not move along lines of force

Comment: There's no 'of course' about it; it's a very common misconception that charged particles move along electric field lines. It's also not uncommon for a student to write 'photon' for 'proton'. Photons carry no charge and are unaffected by an electric field. I refrain from adding 'of course' to the last sentence.